# Is Transmit Power Control technology implemented in iPads?

Tags: wifi

Transmit Power Control (TPC) is a mechanism used by Wi-Fi emitters to lower signal power in order to reduce interference with other wireless networks (and, in mobile devices, save battery).

Is this algorithm implemented in any model of iPad?

Comment: This is a Cisco technology.  Out of curiosity, why is this important and what difference will it make whether it has this capability or not?

Comment: I'd like to know - or better, I would have liked to know, since I posted this question one year ago :) - if iPads have the capability of reduce signal power and thus get a better Wi-Fi quality when there is strong interference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Broadcom question, and not an Apple question.  However, I wanted to provide some basic info on how the "low power mode" of the WLAN chip and iOS.

Lowering the transmit power is handled by the wireless chip, not by Apple itself.  For example, in the iPhone5 it uses the [Broadcom BCM5334](http://www.anandtech.com/show/5601/broadcom-announces-new-combo-chips-bcm4334-bcm43241-shows-80211ac-once-more) chip which is capable of low power consumption (40-50% less than the previous generation) and "dramatically reduced standby power by 3 orders of magnitude."

Looking at the [specs of the BCM4334](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi54svrmqbRAhUD6SYKHaEuDtcQFggpMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cypress.com%2Ffile%2F298706%2Fdownload&usg=AFQjCNE-ODTQa4sgC_hcmd1KvFXk9SHIpQ&sig2=ZFMGpBB-D3qvKuQlWj6KAA), we find that it has "*Programmable dynamic power management*"  Going into the details we find that it the BCM4334 WLAN power states are described as follows:

> - Active mode — All WLAN blocks in the BCM4334 are powered up and fully functional with active carrier sensing and frame transmission
>     and receiving. All required regulators are enabled and put in the most
>     efficient mode based on the load current. Clock speeds are dynamically
>     adjusted by the PMU sequencer.
> - Doze mode — The radio, analog domains, and most of the linear regulators are powered down. The rest of the BCM4334 remains powered
>     up in an IDLE state. All main clocks (PLL, crystal oscillator or TCXO)
>     are shut down to reduce active power to the minimum. The 32.768 kHz
>     LPO clock is available only for the PMU sequencer. This condition is
>     necessary to allow the PMU sequencer to wake up the chip and
>     transition to Active mode. In Doze mode, the primary power consumed is
>     due to leakage current.
> - Deep-sleep mode — Most of the chip including both analog and digital domains and most of the regulators are powered off. Logic states in
>     the digital core are saved and preserved into a retention memory in
>     the always-ON domain before the digital core is powered off. Upon a
>     wake-up event triggered by the PMU timers, an external interrupt or a
>     host resume through the HSIC or SDIO bus, logic states in the digital
>     core are restored to their pre-deep-sleep settings to avoid lengthy HW
>     reinitialization.
> - Power-down mode — The BCM4334 is effectively powered off by shutting down all internal regulators. The chip is brought out of this mode by
>     external logic re-enabling the internal regulators.

The algorithm that is used to lower power consumption/output will be specific to Broadcom and unrelated to Apple.  iOS only puts the chip into power one of the power states; it doesn't manage the power states.

Now, for the main question...

> Is Transmit Power Control implemented in iPads?

If it uses this chip (iPad3), then YES.

> The BCM4334 also supports Transmit Power Control on the STA together
>   with standard Bluetooth TPC to limit mutual interference and receiver
>   desensitization. Preemption mechanisms are utilized to prevent AP
>   transmissions from colliding with Bluetooth frames. Improved channel
>   classification techniques have been implemented in Bluetooth for
>   faster and more accurate detection and elimination of interferers
>   (including non-WLAN 2.4 GHz interference).